# Cannot find a manifest file

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I put all the source files (xml manifest, JS files, etc.) of an Excel add-in to a folder `\\Mac\Home\`. In `Excel for Desktop`, the manifest file appears in `SHARED FOLDER`.

To learn how to implement `Add-in Commands`, I create another Excel add-in project by Visual Studio, it generates many files including [an xml file](http://pastebin.com/U9e2XD3X). I make `SourceLocation` pointed to the right html file (i.e., `\\Mac\Home\Home.html`). Then I am able to debug the project from Visual Studio, which opens a workbook in Excel. And there is indeed an add-in command.

So I copy the xml file which enables add-in command to the folder `\\Mac\Home` and replace my initial manifest. However, this time, Excel for Windows could not find the manifest in `SHARED FOLDER`.

Does anyone know what's wrong there?

**Edit 1:** As I write in the comment, if I remove the part `VersionOverrides`, the manifest appears in `SHARED FOLDER`. So the problem comes from the content of 
`VersionOverrides`.

I copied `Button16x16.png`, `Button32x32.png` and `Button80x80.png` to `\\Mac\Home\Images\`, and the folder `Functions` to `\\Mac\Home\Functions\`. Then I replaced everywhere `~remoteAppUrl` by `\\Mac\Home` to generate [this new xml file](http://pastebin.com/Acq7RzVv). It still does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Troubleshooting manifest issues:

1. Modify the id number (guid) in the manifest.
2. Make sure the manifest follows the schema exactly, including correct ordering of elements.
3. Verify that Excel is pointing to the correct Shared Folder location; check Options > Trust Center > Trusted Add-In Catalogs and verify that "show in menu" is selected
4. Restart Excel
5. Click the Refresh button in the Insert Add-Ins dialog

Comment: To add to Michael's #1, each manifest in the shared folder must have a unique guid.

Comment: Actually, I have already tested these points... For example, if I remove totally `VersionOverrides`, the manifest appears in the shared folder. So the problem comes from the things of `VersionOverrides`...

Comment: Is your VersionOverrides taken directly from a sample? If not, try that first and see if it works. Then change one line at a time from the sample.

Comment: I debugged it one line at a time, and finally I realised that **the requirement is that all the `DefaultValue` in `Resources` must be HTTPS, instead of local files**.